# Dynamics CRM: Merge Lead into Contact

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to merge a Lead into a Contact?  We have programmatically merged two Contacts through a MailRequest API call but would like to merge a Lead into a Contact.

If it isn't possible to do this kind of merge, is there a workaround?  We thought about creating a Contact, performing a Contact merge and deactivating the temporary Contact.

Thanks for any help.

Richard

Answer (score 2):

Typically merges are used to merge two records from the same entity - As far as I know there is no way to merge records across entity types.

If the lead is closed and you no longer wish to use it, you could create a workflow that creates a contact, copies some information from the lead over, creates a connection between the two records and then deactivates the lead.

This way you can still see the lead that generated the contact (and audit information about the lead), but the contact is where to go to get the most up to date information.